# d3 js bar chart not working in mozilla firefox

Tags: javascript, d3.js, bar-chart

I have implemented a d3 js bar chart with reference to the following [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/60we6hkn/105/) link.It working fine with chrome.In firefox web browser  tags are hidden.

```
<body>   <h1>D3.js Bar Chart Demo</h1>   <p>
    Click on the bar to delete it.   </p>   <div>
    <button onclick="changeData()">New</button>
    <button onclick="appendData()">Append</button>
    <button onclick="sortData()">Sort</button>   </div>   <svg id="chart"></svg>   <p>
    Click on the bar to delete it.   </p>   <div>
    <button onclick="changeData()">New</button>
    <button onclick="appendData()">Append</button>
    <button onclick="sortData()">Sort</button>   </div>   <div class="trans-fore">
    <div id="tooltip"></div>   </div> </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is about the `clipPath` element. Chrome is quite permissive about element declaration but not Firefox.
To get your fiddle working, change:

```
svg.append('clippath')
  .attr('id', 'chart-area')
  .append('rect')
  .attr({
  x: Chart.margin.left + Chart.sideWidth,
  y: Chart.margin.top,
  width: BarArea.width,
  height: BarArea.height,
});
```

To:

```
svg.append('defs').append('clipPath')
  .attr('id', 'chart-area')
  .append('rect')
  .attr({
  x: Chart.margin.left + Chart.sideWidth,
  y: Chart.margin.top,
  width: BarArea.width,
  height: BarArea.height,
});
```

Here is the working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/60we6hkn/106/).